# Play Store apparently ignoring my supports-screens settings

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet, google-play

The company I work for recently released some apps which were specifically designed to work on phones only. To make sure the apps wouldn't be downloadable on tablets, we added the `<supports-screens />` tag to our AndroidManifest.

Our tag looks like this:

```
<supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

However, we're still able to download the app on our Asus Transformer TF101, our Samsung tab 10.1 and Transformer Prime.

Due to this, users have been downloading our app on tablets and reporting problems which we knew we would have in advance, hence why we're trying to keep users from downloading it on tablets.

What are we doing wrong? Am I missing something here which still makes it show up for tablets? When I check the Developer's Console it even says the app supports xlargescreens, even though I clearly said it doesn't.

So what could be going on here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what your did you mentioned any targetSdkVersion there?

Comment: Our targetSdkVersion is 10, minumum is 8. We're supporting everything between 2.2 to 4.0.4, except for tablets. It works perfectly fine on all phones though.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer Have you included x-hdpi layouts while designing it, by any chance? I reckon you wouldn't have done that since you don't want to support x-large screens, but just cross verifying..

Comment: Nope, we didn't. Hdpi is as high as we went.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer Alright then. This is really weird. I would suggest you to mail Google directly, since it looks like the job of Google Play's filters. This could very well be a bug. My suggestion would be that you can take this step when nothing else shows up by the end of this road.. Sadly, I don't know the solution..

Comment: Turns out supports-screens does not filter devices if they are larger than what the app "supports". It will just scale the app up. Instead, what we need is <compatible-screens> as Padma Kumar answered. It's something Google prefers you not to use, but sometimes you just have to.

Comment: Hmm ok.. I actually found out almost similar thing and put up an answer. Guess I was too late :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `<supports-screens>`  You can only restrict the small devices from having the app available - all other screen sizes will have the app available even if it's is set to false in manifest.

this support screen will allow your app to run in screen size in your xlarge screen some times you can see in your xlarge screen you can see other app running as phone screen.

for market filter you need to use `<compatible-screens>`

[Link here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. Must have overlooked it in the docs. It may be a last resort solution, but it's exactly what we needed for now.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoted here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge) is `android:xlargeScreens` in the `<supports-screens>` tag. It states,

> Indicates whether the application supports extra large screen form-factors. An xlarge screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "large" screen, such as a tablet (or something larger) and may require special care on the application's part to make good use of it, though it may rely on resizing by the system to fill the screen.
>
> The default value for this actually varies between some versions, so
>   it's better if you explicitly declare this attribute at all times.
>   Beware that setting it "false" will generally enable screen
>   compatibility mode.
>
> This attribute was introduced in API level 9.

The intricacies of Screen Compatibility Mode are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html). Hope this helps.